# Displaying 4 layers of lists in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have to display events that are sorted by date. Json looks like this:

```
[{
    year: Int,
    months: [{
        month: String,
        days:[{
            date:String,
            events:[{
                title: String
                description: String
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

So I have an array inside of an array inside of...
For displaying the 1st layer (years), I created a recycler view + adapter. But what now? How do I display months, days in months, events on those days?

On screen it should look like this:

```
2000
  Jan
    1st
      Stuff 1 | Stuff 2
    20th
      Stuff 3
  Apr
    2nd
      Stuff 4
2001
  Jul
    15th
       Stuff 5 | Stuff 6
```

where years, months and days are vertical, and the events are horizontal. All vertical elements should behave like one element in a sense that when you scroll, they all scroll.

I found examples only with 2 layers, 1 vertical + 1 horizontal. How to handle 4 layers?

Comment: I think you need `SectionedRecyclerView`  . First you need to figure out how you want them to sectioned .

Comment: I'm not following you, do you want to display a scrollable list or lists within lists? If you want the former, then you need to _transform_ your data into a flat list of "things" to bind to the RV adapter. In your e.g.: 2000/2001 would be "YearViewHolders", Jan, Apr, etc. are MonthViewHolders; you'd have DayViewHolders and "StuffViewHolders". Flatten your arrays ahead of time, format your data to make your RV/Adapter's life (and yours) easier. Use a `ListAdapter<T,K>` and use a `DiffUtil` to simplify your updates.

Comment: To extend: think about the "complexity" of flattening this data, you have to iterate, add to collections, create the data models, and assign a type, etc. If you didn't do this, RecyclerView(s) and Adapter(s) would have to work in sync to orchestrate all this for you, on top of their already complicated set of responsibilities.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I want to display a scrollable list (vertical, for years, months, days, and horizontal for events). If I flatten the list, how can I display different design for each of the elements (for instance year red, month green with indent etc)? Also, how can I know which months are in which year, if I don't have monts-year relationship anymore?

Comment: Different Design: You use the `getViewType(...)` method to return different ViewHolder implementations for each "element". An example of using a viewType is available here: https://github.com/Gryzor/GridToShowAds (look at this adapter: https://github.com/Gryzor/GridToShowAds/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/neutobo/recyclerviewwithads/ThingAdapterWithAds.kt). As for the 2nd question: you do this in your "Model(s)" When you're creating your "List<Things>". This is the key component of your problem. Once you've flattened this, the rest is "easy".

Comment: As for the "vertical vs horizontal" that will indeed require two RVs or some form of horizontal scrollable "row" (it can be a viewHolder of the RV that is specifically inflating a list of "stuff" in a HorizontalSwipe View or similar. But keep in mind these are different problems. First figure out how you want to structure your List Of "Things" to display, then work on "the presentation" of said things. I am simplifying here (I don't have access to your problem domain) but this is the way I'd head towards.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini thank you, I will try to do what you suggested :)

Comment: I've put it all in an answer in the hopes it gives you a better overview. Good luck with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify what I mean.

#### Model(s)

You need to *flatten* your model so it can be a list of "Things".

You can have an abstract `Thing` that contains some basic model info, like an `identifier` and maybe a `parentIdentifier` if you're concerned about how to link the things together.

Ultimately, each model needs to have at least a `type`. E.g.: (**this is going to be kotlin pseudo-code, just letting you know...**, there may be typos or inconsistencies, but this is to give you an idea how to solve your data problem)

`RemoteThing` (and `RemoteYear, month, etc`) are imaginary classes that I think you may have if you had parsed your JSON into "some form of data model".

Now this process is going to transform this RemoteDomainObjects into Local Domain problems (that is, data suited to your local domain/problem).

```
// type can be an "enum" I just simplified with an int. 1 = year, 2 = month, 3 = day, 4 = stuff. :)

// The "Base" of your model(s)
class Thing(val id: String, val type: Int, val parentId: String? = null)

// Years don't have a "parent" (they are "root elements")
class Year(val id: String, val year Int) : Thing(id, type = 1, parentId = null)

// Month's parentId is gonna be the Year's ID this month is in. 
class Month(val id: String, val month: Int, val parentId: String?) : Thing(id, type = 2, parentId = ...)

// Repeat for day...
class Day(val id: String, val day Int, val parentId: String?, events: List<Events>) : Thing(id, type = 3, parentId = ...)

// E.g of an "event" (if you need id/parent, add those too)
data class Events(val title: String, val desc: String)
```

#### Flattening the Data

You receive your JSON array of array of array of arrays... somewhere in your code.
Call a `UseCase` or create a `class MyDataTransformator` :) that will receive all this Json (or the List<List<List...> if you already created that model) and iterates it one by one, creating a flat `List<Thing>()`.

Pseudo code time...

Imagine you have a List<RemoteThings...> (this is what you parsed your JSON into)

1. Iterate the root (years), outer loop.

```
val results = mutableListOf<Thing>()

 // You're gonna need a list of years
 val years = mutableListOf<Year>()

remoteThings.forEach { rt -> //remote thing :) 

   // you're iterating the years... so create a new Year...
   val year = Year(rt.id, year = rt.year) //years don't have parentId.
   
   // Each year has it's own list of months.
   val months = mutableListOf<Month>()

   // Now you need to iterate the months inside this year...
   rt.months.forEach { rm -> //remoteMonth ;) 
       
       val month = Month(rm.id, rm.month, parentId = year.id)

       val days = mutableListOf<Day>()

       // Now you need to iterate the days inside this month...
       rm.days.forEach { rd -> //remoteDay 

          val day = Day(rd.id, rd.day, parentId = month.id)
          
          val events = mutableListOf<Events>() //each day gets its own events' list

          // Iterate the "stuff" (events... for this day)
          rd.events.forEach { re -> //remoteEvent
               val event = Event(re.title, re.desc) //does this need a parent? maybe?
               // add each event to this list..
               events.add(event)
          }

          // finished iterating the "Day" events, save them
          day.events = events 
     
          // Save the day (always wanted to say that)
          days.add(day)
       }

       // Finished with the days on this month, save them in the month.
       month.days = days

       // save the month
       months.add(month)
   }

   // Finished with the months of this year, save them in the year...
   year.months = months
   
   // and finally, save the year
   years.add(year)
}

// finished iterating all the years... save the "things" and pass this onto your adapter. 
results.addAll(years)
```

I hope that makes sense.

Finally have an `class yourAdapter : ListAdapter<Thing, ViewModel>(...)` and do `adapter.submitList(results)` and your 2nd problem begins.

#### Adapter

I won't go into too much detail here (please check the infinite number of examples of RecyclerViews with Types and nested Types like the one [I linked above](https://github.com/Gryzor/GridToShowAds/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/neutobo/recyclerviewwithads/ThingAdapterWithAds.kt) that shows you how you can differentiate between a flat object to inflate a different viewHolder that will display a different UI.

In that example, you can see there are *two types* of objects:

`ColoredViewHolder` and `AdViewHolder`.

They inflate different layouts and therefore look different.

#### DiffUtil?

Notice you need a `DiffUtil.ItemCallback<...>` to pass onto your ListAdapter's constructor. In that same file you can see a simple example of one (basically, it allows the adapter to compare items to know which/when/what changed when you `submitList(..)`.

#### Conclusion

You started the journey hitting the wall against how to handle nested and structured data in a RecyclerView, and now I've shifted your problem towards a data Transformation and then a presentation issue, but both have a better synergism with each other, since each problem makes the life of the other problem easier.

#### Horizontal?

As for the horizontal display of day events, you can have your `EventListViewHolder` have and manage a small(er) internal RecyclerView in horizontal mode (and its adapter) or you can try to leverage something like a [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView); in the end it doesn't matter, so as long as you keep the problems contained and separated. That is: the external RV, doesn't care/know how this is displayed by the ViewHolder; and neither do the Data Transformation process above.

Each class/function has a small/limited amount of responsibilities.

#### Nesting Loops?!!

Yes, I know it looks crazy, but such is the data you have, nested and in collections, so you ought to transverse it to transform it. There are many ways to do that, mine was pseudo code to give you an idea what you have and what you want.

If you use Coroutines, that could be a suspend function that does this in the computing "dispatcher" while your ViewModel waits for the data before it can pass it onto the UI.

*This is the way* (I'd go with) :)

Good luck!